# How do I import checkbox field values using DataGrab?

Tags: matrix, datagrab, import, checkbox

How do I format checkbox field values in an XML DataGrab import? I should mention that this checkbox field is in a Matrix but I am not sure if that will affect anything.

I've tried using the usual PHP_EOL and pipes to separate multiple values but neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a normal, EE checkbox, you should just need to supply pipe-delimited values (eg, One|Two|Three).

If you are using a Field Pack checkbox, these aren't currently supported within Matrix fields, but I can add it pretty easily if you need it.

Comment: It is a Field Pack checkbox field. I thought I had updated my question with that information but I guess I didn't. Sorry about that! Also, this is for an EE 2.9.3 installation.

Comment: Is this a quick change or should I just change the field type to a regular checkbox field? I don't believe it is crucial for us to stick with the Field Pack option in this case.

Comment: Wait, the regular checkboxes field isn't supported in Matrix. So I *am* limited to using the Field Pack column type.